# IGraphicsCaptureItemInterop.CreateForWindow encounter winrt::hresult_access_denied ？

Tags: c++, electron, windows-runtime

`electron` (*run as admin*) loads *dll* ***A*** and ***A*** loads *dll* ***B*** which calls `IGraphicsCaptureItemInterop.CreateForWindow` but I encounter `winrt::hresult_access_denied`.

Is it a program permission problem?

If I just load *dll* ***B*** and then call `IGraphicsCaptureItemInterop.CreateForWindow`, is it going to work?

Comment: MFC load dll B and then call IGraphicsCaptureItemInterop.CreateForWindow work well but nodejs load dll A then A load dll B not work encounter  winrt::hresult_access_denied

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar with CEF. Chromium has sandboxing code to reduce process privileges (MITIGATION_HARDEN_TOKEN_IL_POLICY), causing CreateForWindow to fail. You can work around this on CEF by specifying the CEF sandbox info struct to CefInitialize, which doesn't specify MITIGATION_HARDEN_TOKEN_IL_POLICY, but I've never used Electron, so I don't know if they have an equivalent workaround.

Comment: the electron app run as administrator, Inside dll I print the current process IntegrityLevel >= SECURITY_MANDATORY_HIGH_RID